# imagemagick return file format using identify

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, file-type, identify

Current I am able to get the file format using `identify -verbose filename.hpg`, I get `Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)` from the array.

How can I return this exact same line using the -format option, 
example: `identify -verbose -format "%XXX" filename.hpg` whereas XXX is the format charcter to return `Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve exactly? What is the end result you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can more simply do this:

```
exec("identifiy -verbose filename.hpg | grep Format:")
```

Or use the format string sequences as documented in http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php - but there's seemingly no equivalent for the textual type description.

```
exec("identify -format 'Format: %m' filename.hpg");
```